# Can the ubuntu-gnome-remix tag be renamed to ubuntu-gnome?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [ubuntu-gnome-remix](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-gnome-remix) tag is currently the official tag for questions relating to the GNOME flavor of Ubuntu. However, at the time this tag started being used, it was not yet an official flavor and "Ubuntu GNOME Remix" was the working name of the project.

As of March 2013, the flavor is [official](https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/msg00274.html) and has been named "Ubuntu GNOME", see the flavor's [official site](http://ubuntugnome.org/) and [wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME). It would be good to see the "-remix" dropped from the tag and the official flavor name used instead.

There are 36 questions tagged with [ubuntu-gnome-remix](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-gnome-remix), can we have this tag bulk renamed to [ubuntu-gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-gnome) which is not yet in use? Any objections?

Comment: Only 36 questions? Why not manually?

Comment: @Braiam Because I'm new here and I don't know the threshold of pain for renames :) I am certainly willing to go through and retag manually and copy/update the tag wiki if that's more appropriate.

Comment: Go ahead and start renaming them. Try not to flood the front page with too much at a time though. Maybe 6 for now? Actually, it might just be easier to create ubuntu-gnome and then synonymize them since they mean the same thing anyway. That would also prevent other people from recreating this tag. cc @Braiam

Comment: @Seth OK started retagging 6 as you suggest.